# Spark SQL read csv with whitepsace delimiter and ignore whitespace inside brackets

Tags: csv, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, removing-whitespace

I am trying to read a text file which has lines like this:

```
a [b c] "d e" f
```

This code works fine except for parsing `[b c]`, it splits `b` and `c` into separate columns. Is there a way to ignore the whitespace between them?

```
display( spark.read.load(file_path, format="csv",sep = ' ', header="false"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Let it split ... I think its no problem. You can try this

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lit
df
.withColumn("timestamp", concat($"col1", lit(" "),$"col2"))
.withColumn("timestamp", $"timestamp".cast("date"))
```

where col1 = 24/Sep/2014:22:25:44 & col2 = +0000

Comment: I apologize the edited the question to be more generic. But your answer still holds and I think it solves my problem. Please change the column names in your answer to match the question if you would, thanks!